# Bootstrap 4 sidebar with dropdowns, keep open on click

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 for a collapsible sidebar with dropdowns.

```
<nav id="sidebar">
    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <li><a href="dashboard.html">Admin Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pages</a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#usersSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Users</a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="usersSubmenu">
                <li>
                    <a href="users.html">List Users</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="users_add.html">Add New User</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="general_settings.html">General Settings</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="profile.html">My Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Is there a way if a user clicks, for example, Home 2 in the first dropdown, to keep the dropdown open while on that page?  While the use is viewing Home 2, the entire HOME dropdown should remain open.

Thanks!
Rick

Comment: You mean that Home 2 would be another page? So you need to keep menu opened on page load?

Comment: yes, home 2 will link to an actual page when complete. Currently it's just linked to #.  I'm trying to get it so if a submenu item is the active page, that part of the menu stays open.

Comment: Maybe a better example would be, if a user clicks on users.html link, the USERS submenu would stay open after users.html loads.

Comment: Do you have static pages or you have back-end process (php etc.)?